# How to implement search and filter in lektor

Tags: lektor

Im trying to implement blog in lektor same like my wordpress site but i want search feature on my blog. What are ways to search and filter the content in lektor.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, but of course none of them directly supported by Lektor:

- On swingrock.be I have implemented search functionality with `tipue`, a Javascript libary.
- On improblog.be I have implemented search functionality with a Google Programmable Search Engine https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Both work well, but Tipue requires some more fiddling to get right and also makes your build process heavier. With a Google Programmable Search Engine, a possible problem is that you won't have much control over it.